# Is it possible to boil wort too quickly?

Tags: beer, boil, propane-burner

I recently picked up [this burner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000291GBQ) and was excited to use it to bring my wort to a boil. I had it cranked up pretty high and it took about 15 minutes to bring 6 gallons of wort to a rolling boil in a stainless steel kettle. Is there an ideal time it should take to bring the wort to a boil? If I boil it too quickly is it possible that I'll burn the wort? Is there a way to tell if I am burning my wort?

Comment: What is your starting point? Off the sparge (170f/76c)? From tap to boil then adding extract?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Commercial micro-brewers can bring 10 barrels (2880 pints) to the boil in 30 - 45 mins using a gas jet of flame in a pipe that passes through the kettle - can't remember the technical name for it. What they do do, though, is recirculate the wort whilst they heat. This will keep it on the move and prevent hot spots/scorching/caramelising and any other problems that might occur from high temperatures acting on the wort.

So, I think you should be careful if you use too high a heat to boil it quickly. Consider keeping it on the move. I am sure overheating will be apparent by dark deposits on the 'hot' zone of your kettle. These deposits can contain carcinogens, so it is best not to let them build up.

Comment: +1 on the dark spots. They are probably a bad sign. 15min for 6 gal, while TOTALLY AWESOME, is probably more power than you need. Dial it down a touch.

Comment: I heard a interesting story that an electric element boil was imparting 20+ SRM to the color of a notable ruby brown ale due to caramelization. A vigorous boil is important and if you can get their without imparting color or flavor changes and no scorching of the kettle, getting there quickly is ok.

fwiw I have used those burners without incident to the final product as long as I was not adding ingredients that could stick to the bottom and burn.